# Toggle a simple navigation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a **very simple** navigation menu. It has to be clickable. So when using this code

```js
var isActive = true;

function toggleMenu(){
    var content = $("#navContent");

    isActive = !isActive; // toggle the current menu state
    if(isActive) {
        content.display = "block"; // show the items
    } else {
        content.display = "none"; // hide all items
        content.position = "absolute";
        content.zIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="toggleMenu()">

<div id="navContainer">
    <button id="navBtn" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
    <div id="navContent">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

and pressing on the menu button, I get into the `toggleMenu()` function but the items don't hide.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is the function being fired?

Comment: `$("#navContent")` returns a jQuery object, but to directly access .style you would need the reference to a DOM element. But jQuery has methods to manipulate element styles, so there is not need to mix these two approaches in the first place. It has .show/.hide as well (although these are not the ideal way to do this either - you should rather just toggle a class, and leave formatting to your stylesheet.)

Comment: Not sure why you don't just use `toggle()` for this and set the display to hidden in css to hide the menu upon page rendering but if you want to continue with the method you're using then you should be targeting the `css` before trying to target and change a `css` property. **Example:** `content.css("display", "block");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a rather odd mix of plain JS and jQuery. I'd suggest using one or the other. Here's a simple version of your code using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#navBtn').click(function() {
    $('#navContent').toggle();
  }); 
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navContainer">
  <button id="navBtn">Menu</button>
  <div id="navContent">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, `element.toggle()` keeps the code very clean :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to make a CSS class that hides the elements, which is then toggled by JS. This answer doesn't require jQuery

```js
function toggleMenu(){
    document.getElementById('navContent').classList.toggle("hidden")
}
```

```css
#navContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navContent button {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navContainer">
    <button id="navBtn" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</button>
    <div id="navContent" class="hidden">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it to:

```js
$("#navBtn").click(function() {
  $("#navContent").toggle();
});
```

```css
#navContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navContent {
  display: none;
}

#navContent button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="navContainer">
    <button id="navBtn">Menu</button>
    <div id="navContent">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
      <button>3</button>
      <button>4</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```